# Failing checks for files on hidden Windows network share

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows

I have an internal web application that needs to allow users to upload files to a directory which the application accesses via a hidden network share. A windows domain user account has been set up for this purpose and the code uses Windows Identity impersonation for reading/writing files to the location.

A call to `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)` passing an instance of the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` writes the files to the specified directory on the network share. The files are written to the directory correctly but are all named `BodyPart_[GUID]` so I need to rename them to something more meaningful. After writing the files to the directory I call `File.Exists(file.LocalFileName)` to ensure the file is found before attempting to rename them. The problem is this call always results in a false result saying the file(s) does not exist. I saw suggestions to use `FileInfo` instead of `File.Exists` when using network shares but that is also not working.

Below is the relevant code in the API Controller - I can't see what else I might be doing wrong.

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials("domain","username", "password");
using (var userHandle = credentials.LogonUser(LogonType.NewCredentials))
{
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(userHandle, async () =>
    {
        var dir = GlobalConfig.Case.UploadDirectory;
        dir = Path.Combine(dir, caseReference);

        // Check the directory exist before attempting to upload documents
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(dir);

        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        
        // Iterate over each uploaded file
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            var originalFilename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            var newFilename = Path.Combine(dir, string.Concat(caseReference, "_", originalFilename));
            var uniqueFileName = MakeUniqueFilename(newFilename);

            try
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                if (fileInfo.Exists)
                {
                    // Rename the file to case ref + original filename
                    // It seems we can't move (rename) a file using a network share but can copy/delete
                    File.Copy(file.LocalFileName, uniqueFileName, true);
                    File.Delete(file.LocalFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Warning("Missing file {LocalFileName}", file.LocalFileName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "Unable to rename file from {OriginalFilename} to {UniqueFileName}",
                    Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName), uniqueFileName);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you write the file(s) to a local folder instead of a network share?

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, it works as expected with a local directory

Comment: I've tried mapping the folder to a drive letter but that also fails with `Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\Folder'`.

Comment: Drive mappings won't work as expected from within a Win32 service. UNC paths should work, though.

Comment: > £UNC paths should work" - On rare occasions, it does seem to work but 99% of the time it doesn't and so it can't be relied upon. There is no apparent reason why it might on the odd occasion manage to rename the file.